# Unable to use .replaceWith(jQuery('#content') properly in CodeIginiter

Tags: php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I am unable to use `.replaceWith(jQuery('#content')` jQuery function properly in Codeigniter. I am able to replace the "content" part of my html. But the page background image is not coming.

**In Controller**

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('common');
        $this->load->view('guest');
    }
public function form()
    {
        $this->load->view('common');
        $this->load->view('Form');
    }
```

**In view** (***form.php***)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#content1').replaceWith(jQuery('#content'));
});
</script>
<div id="content" style="overflow: scroll">
...
...
</div>
```

When I am calling controller like this way...

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('common');
        $this->load->view('Form');
    }
```

everything works fine...

But when I am going to "Form.php" through a hyperlink, page loads but without the page background. My page background is located at 
C:\xampp\htdocs\php\CodeIgniter\folder\a.php

In the "common.php" I am calling the page background like this way

```
<body background="folder/a.jpg">
```

Please help someone to solve my problem...

Answer (score 0):

actually there is no error I found on here. To prove that i used same of your code and try my own. Its work smoothly without bit of error.

My HTML

```
<div id="content1" style="overflow: scroll">
    <p>This is content 1</p>
</div>

<div id="content2" style="overflow: scroll">
    <p>This is content 2</p>
</div>

<hr>
<div id="content3" style="overflow: scroll">
    <p>This is content 3</p>
</div>

<div id="content14" style="overflow: scroll">
    <p>This is content 4</p>
</div>
```

My JS

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#content1').replaceWith(jQuery('#content2'));
});


$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#content3').replaceWith(jQuery('#content4'));
});
```

[JsFiddle Preview](http://jsfiddle.net/abdulla_nilam/94htzgh8/)

> I think you maybe missing `content` div or wrong argument with it. As well as make sure if you including the file to this its included correctly.